# Update string based on number text in Single column

Tags: sql

Example I have this varchar 'XXXOXOXXOX' and 'XOXOXOXXXX'. I need update the 5th 'X' text to 'O' from total 10 text in single string column. So the result after update will be  'XXXOOOXXOX' and 'XOXOOOXXXX'. Please help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do in MySQL:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = CONCAT(LEFT(col, 4), 'O', SUBSTR(col, 6))
WHERE SUBSTR(col, 5, 1) = 'X';
```

A more generic ANSI SQL answer would be this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = LEFT(col, 4) || 'O' || SUBSTR(col, 6))
WHERE col LIKE '____X%';
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
UPDATE yourTable
    SET col = STUFF(col, 5, 1, '0')
    WHERE col = '____X%';
```

In MySQL,

```
UPDATE yourTable
    SET col = INSERT(col, 5, 1, '0')
    WHERE col = '____X%';
```